# Find combination value ${n\choose r}$ that is greater than $10^{18}$.

Tags: algorithms, combinations

I am stuck in one point in making algorithm. The problem is related with combination.

I need to calculate the minimum value of $x$, for which it satisfies below condition,

> $${x \choose x/2} = 10^{18}.$$

But I didn't solve this using paper work. To solve this I wrote one code, that is also fails to solve the problem.

**My code is here:-**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long int choose(unsigned long long int n, unsigned long long int k) {
    if(k > n) return 0;

    unsigned long long int r = 1;

    for(unsigned long long int d = 1; d <= k; d++) {
        r *= n--;
        r /= d;
    }
    return r;
}

main() {
    int count = 0;
    for(unsigned long long int i = 2; i < 100000000; i += 10000) {
        if( choose(i, i/2) >= 10^18 ) count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to solve this. Looking forward for your kind reply.

Comment: I just ran a test with your code. It seems at least on my machine there is a problem with overflow/signed/unsigned arithmetic. I get -1961361076 for choose(34,17) which is off by $2^{32}$.

Comment: By the way, in C++ `10^18` is $24$. `^` is the binary exclusive or.

Comment: @gammatester Yes I also observe overflow problem, how can I remove that.

Comment: @DanielFischer By `10^18` , means `10*10*10....18 times`

Comment: Yes, you mean that. And I understood. But if you write `10^18` in C++ (or saner languages like C, Java, C#), you get the bitwise xor of the two `int` values `10` and `18`, which is `24`.

Comment: Do you have changed the loop to `i++` instead of `i += 10000` and use `1000000000000000000ULL` for $10^{18}$ and still get overflows? Then I can't help as it seems to be compiler dependent. Make sure `unsigned long long int` is 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why your algorithm fails (do you have checked some small examples for your function *choose*?), but here is an answer. For an approxation $a(x)$ use the Stirling's formula, [Catalan numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html), or others to get 
$$a(x) = {x \choose x/2} \approx 2^x  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}. $$
Solving $a(x)=10^{18}$ gives the solution $x_m\approx 63.110$. Now since you are seeking integer solutions, we have
$${62 \choose 31} = 465428353255261088 < 10^{18}, \quad {64 \choose 32} = 1832624140942590534 > 10^{18},$$ therefore your answer is $x=64$.

Comment: Can you please tell me value for `x = 63`. As my code fails t calculate this.

Comment: I tried on numbers of online combination calculator, but no one gives correct answer. Can you please give me that, and also tell the method how you calculate ?

Comment: The normal definition of binomial coefficient needs integers. You can use the generalisation
$${n \choose r} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(r+1) \Gamma(n-r+1)}$$ and the you will get
$${63 \choose 31.5} = \frac{\Gamma(64)}{\Gamma(32.5)^2} =
\frac{2658455991569831745807614120560689152}{916312070471295267 \pi} \approx
923498501625073042.084816$$

Comment: How can you calculate this value, please share that link. Please check my above code from value 2 to 62. I think for these value above block is correct.

Comment: Without this I cannot proceed in buiilding my algorithm. Please help me.

Comment: Huh? You **cannot** include it into the above algorithm because **63/2 is no integer**. If you think, that my given value is incorrect, you can use most known multiprecision calculators, for WA use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%2863%2C63%2F2%29

Comment: Thanks!!! My problem solved :)